# Can see topic published but cannot see anything when we echo the topic

Tags: ros, rviz, data, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on a tele-operation mode of a mobile robot, from a control station.

The control station and the robot is connected to the same WIFI network and both can ping to each other.

The problem comes when i want to see the LIDAR map/readings on the control station.

When i rostopic list on my control station, i could see the topic. However, when I echo that topic, i didn't receive any message. When i open RViz and add the map , it doesn't show anything(because the message wasn't received in the first place). RViz freezes too when i try to add the map.
This does not happens to the other topics. For eg, the topic odom can be echo-ed.

I tried with Ethernet , it works(but it has its own issues ), but i need to be connected through a same WIFI network.

What could be the problem here??

1. Too much data being published?(when i do a rostopic echo in the vehicle, my screen would be flooded with values)
2. WIFI connection? (i set up a bidirectional networking by exporting ROS_IP and ROS_MASTER_URI, do i have to do anything else?)
3. RViz issues? (it freezes, turns grey when i try )
4. Any other things i am missing out?

and possible solution for this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257230/can-see-topic-published-but-cannot-see-anything-when-we-echo-the-topic/) by [Azhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27936/azhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2017-03-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-03-17**:
What is your ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_IP on both computers?

**Comment by [Azhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27936/azhar/) on 2017-03-17**:
ok.

A : Control station, my laptop
B: mobile robot

in A,

```
export ROS_IP=<IP address of A>

export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://<IP address of B>:11311/
```

in B (MASTER),

```
export ROS_IP=<IP address of B>
roscore
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the issue by downloading the LIDAR MAP(.yaml ) in my laptop and run from there. Thanks people.
I encountered a new problem which i will be opening a new question on.

---

Originally posted by [Azhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27936/azhar/) with karma: 100 on 2017-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0